# Storage requirements for MySQL TEXT column

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table called `errormsg2` using MyISAM storage engine with about a dozen columns.

Two of those columns I estimate account for most of the space used for each row, and they are of datatype TEXT. They are `backtrace` and `msg`.

I'm trying to estimate the amount of storage required for each row, and I came upon the following contradiction:

`show table status where name = 'errormsg2';` shows that `(data_length + index_length) / rows` is about 778 bytes per row.

`select avg( bit_length( em.backtrace ) + bit_length( em.msg ) ) / 8 from errormsg2 em;` shows an average of 899 bytes of text per row from just these two columns.

How is it possible that the table store more data than it uses? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider is encoding issues. UTF-8 for example uses 5 bytes for some characters. If you have no data, or variable data, the database is forced to assume the worst: that every character could be 5 bytes in length. Thus, it may allocate more than it actually needs to use.

Note that UTF-16, although purportedly only 2 bytes, can also fall prey to the same sort of issues: it has to encode surrogate pairs, which are 4 bytes long. UTF-16 has multiple other issues, and [some](http://utf8everywhere.org/) advocate always using UTF-8